# Surjective homomorphism preserves planarity?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, planar-graphs

I was just wondering if for surjective homomorphism of G to H, where G is planar hold that H is planar as well.

This is clearly false for non-surjective ones, but for surjective?

How it is with other usual graph properties? Is there some survey?

Comment: That just makes $G$ a spanning subgraph of $H$ (that is, $H$ has all the edges $G$ has, and can possibly have more). A simple counter-example to your conjecture: If $G$ is of order $n$, then there is a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $K_n$, the complete graph of the same order, which is non-planar for $n \ge 5$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, of course. I'll delete that. I wrote "surjective", but I was thinking "bijective" without realizing it. In fact, it is injectivity that is important. If there is an injective homomorphism from $H$ to $G$, with $G$ planar, then $H$ must be planar.

Comment: Come to think of it, my first comment is (partly) wrong too. That doesn't make $G$ a spanning subgraph of $H$, unless the homomorphism is bijective [for $G$ could, in general, be larger than $H$]. But the counter-example is correct.

Answer (score 3):

No, not even if you strengthen "surjective" to require that every *edge* in $H$ is the image of at least one edge in $G$.

For example, take $G=C_{10}$ (clearly planar) and $H=K_5$ (well known not to be); then a surjective homomorphism $f:G\to H$ would be given by
$$ \begin{matrix}f(0) = 0 & f(1)=1 & f(2) = 2 & f(3)=3 & f(4)=4 \\
f(5) = 0 & f(6)=2 & f(7)=4 & f(8)=1 & f(9)=3 \end{matrix} $$

By the way, the other direction doesn't work either; there's an obvious surjective homomorphism from $K_{3,3}$ (also well known to be non-planar) to $K_2$ (clearly planar).